# injected HTML Interprets as string only in Dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dom

I am trying to inject an HTML to my Dom like this

```
   var oldhtmlString = // Getting html from an ajax query
  $this.parent('td').find('.newhtml').html ( oldhtmlString);
```

Server side code to generate HTML from database

```
DataSet ds = DataAccessLayer.Instance.ExecuteThisSQLAndGetDataSet("select * from UpdateEmail");
        var table = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable();  
        string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
```

I am getting an HTML string from external source inside a JSON element and I am trying to inject it to an element inside my Dom. But it is injected as string only like shown below

```
        <div class="newhtml">
&lt;div style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana;"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Please note that the values f::1&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;p&gt;This is an automated message. Please DO NOT reply and contact the Warehouse directly for further questions.&lt;/div&gt;
 </div>
```

Original HTML is taken from a database. it looks like this

```
<div style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana;"><p>Please note that the values for CO #  509226, This is an automated message. Please DO NOT reply and contact the Warehouse directly for further questions.</p></div>
```

When it came to client side through ajax in a JSON object it looks like this

```
LogHTML: "<div style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana;"><p>Please note that the values for ::1</td></tr></table><p>This is an automated message. Please DO NOT reply and contact the Warehouse directly for further questions.</p></div>"
```

Can anyone tell me how I could properly show this HTML in my Dom?

> Note: only HTML data format is correct. I have changed data inside that HTML due to privacy reasons, so each of the above HTML code snippets would look little different.

Comment: It seems the original HTML source is escaped. You are using `html` method and it doesn't escape the passed HTML string.

Comment: @Vohuman I don't understand it completely, can you please add it as an answer with proper code and explanation

Comment: Show how `oldhtmlString` looks like, how your Ajax query looks like. Also, did you write the server side code?

Comment: @Tomalak I have added the details now. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
        
var oldhtmlString = '&lt;div style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana;"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Please note that the values f::1&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;p&gt;This is an automated message. Please DO NOT reply and contact the Warehouse directly for further questions.&lt;/div&gt;'

$('.newhtml').html( $('<div/>').html(oldhtmlString).text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newhtml"> </div>
```